# How to implement an "importable namespace"?

Tags: matlab

I know that I can use a class consisting solely of static methods to implement a *namespace* in MATLAB.  E.g.

```
classdef MyNamespace
    methods (Static = true)
        function [...] = foo(...)
            ...
        end
        function [...] = bar(...)
            ...
        end
        ...
    end
end
```

With the above I can call functions `MyNamespace.foo`, `MyNamespace.bar`, etc. (assuming, of course, that the file `MyNamespace.m` is in my search path, or in the current directory).

A paramount feature of this technique is that it allows simulating "namespace variables".  For example, a function within the `methods (Static = true)` could have the form

```
        function out = BAZ(newval)
            persistent val;
            out = val;
            if nargin > 0, val = newval; end
        end
```

With this, the *method* `MyNamespace.BAZ` can mimic a "namespace *variable*" `MyNamespace.BAZ` (though, admittedly, in a *very* cumbersome way).

*This feature is one that I absolutely require*.

The implementation of namespaces described above is ok, but I'd like to be able *import* namespace, so that I can call their functions using their "short" (aka "unqualified") names, such as `foo`, `bar`, etc.

How can I implement a namespace that can be *imported*, in the sense described above?

---

BTW, I'd prefer answers that build on the technique illustrated above (for implementing namespaces), since it's a technique I have some experience with, but I'm also open to alternatives that are not based on this technique.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has a [package](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) system which allows creating a namespace of functions which are also importable.  In short, just drop a directory whose name begins with a `+` in another directory on your path and add your function MATLAB files in that directory.  If you have `MyNamespace.m` in the directory `someDir` then just create:

```
someDir/+MyNamespace/foo.m
someDir/+MyNamespace/bar.m
```

and so on.  You can call them via `MyNamespace.foo, MyNamespace.bar` and [import](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) them:

```
import MyNamespace.foo
```

or:

```
import MyNamespace.*
```